# Resque Problme: Why are queues got stucked in background job processing through resque automatically

Tags: php

I am using resque for background jobs. Sometimes, queues are automatically stucked. Then, we have to kill pids and restart same queue, it will work fine.

**Why does it happens?**

Please help to overcome with this problem.

Comment: is function pcntl_fork available in your PHP?

Comment: Yes, this function is available.